# header text in different blocks not responsive

Tags: html, css

When on smaller screen devices, the following appears in three blocks, and not in one same sentence line (see image). So I want on smaller devices: "Here we start if-statement-text-1 and this is the end". How to fix?

[image]

I need it to look like this on smaller screens... [image]

```css
.text {
  background-color: red;
  padding:20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">Here we start
  <span class="text">if-statement-text-1</span>
  <span class="text">if-statement-text-2</span>and  this is the end!</div>
```

Comment: So you're trying to get it to look like the image?

Comment: @Sacha - No, thats how it looks now, its wrong. I need it to look in one same normal sentence line. Somehow the three blocks are stand-alone and they align side-by-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally certain I understand exactly what you're aiming for, but adding `display: inline-block;` to your `.text` class should make it look closer to your goal.

```css
.text {
  background-color: red;
  padding:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">Here we start
  <span class="text">if-statement-text-1</span>
  <span class="text">if-statement-text-2</span>and  this is the end!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `word-wrap:break-word;` for the `<span>` text.

It even works in IE6, which is a pleasant surprise.

```css
.text {
  background-color: red;
  padding:5px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">Here we start
   <span class="text">if-statement-text-1</span>
   <span class="text">if-statement-text-2</span> and  this is the end! 
</div>
```

Comment: does not work... i still have the 3 blocks of text side by side.

Answer (score 0):

```
.text {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem.